# Unexpected results for addition big numbers with carry on GPU (OpenCL)

Tags: c++, opencl, bignum, boost-compute

I am writing a function to add numbers of arbitrary length on GPU using OpenCL and Boost::compute as frontend.

No error occurs when the numbers are not so big (4096 bits):

```
Bits length: 4096
Limbs Size: 65
Result: [03, ffffffffffffffff, ffffffffffffffff, ... , ffffffffffffffff, ffffffffffffffff, fffffffffffffffe]
Expected: [03, ffffffffffffffff, ffffffffffffffff, ... , ffffffffffffffff, ffffffffffffffff, fffffffffffffffe]
```

But at bigger size of numbers (40960 bits and more) the error occurs in arbitrary digits of the result:

```
Bits length: 40960
Limbs Size: 641
ERROR limb index: 638
ERROR: [... , fffffffffffffffe, ffffffffffffffff, fffffffffffffffe, ...]
EXPECTED: [... , ffffffffffffffff, ffffffffffffffff, ffffffffffffffff, ...]
...
Bits length: 40960
Limbs Size: 641
ERROR limb index: 626
ERROR: [... , fffffffffffffffe, ffffffffffffffff, ffffffffffffffff, ...]
EXPECTED: [... , ffffffffffffffff, ffffffffffffffff, ffffffffffffffff, ...]
```

It seems I didn't foresee some kind of thread synchronization issue.

**But which one?**

Kernel function code:

```cpp
#include <boost/compute/utility/source.hpp>

const char source[] = BOOST_COMPUTE_STRINGIZE_SOURCE (

__kernel void
vaddc64(__global ulong * const a, const __global ulong *b, const uint size, __global ulong * const error)
{
__private size_t gid =get_global_id(0);
__private bool prev_overflow;

    a[gid] +=b[gid];

    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

    prev_overflow = gid ? (a[gid - 1] < b[gid - 1]) : false;

    barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);

    if(prev_overflow)
        ++a[gid];

    //barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE);
}

);
```

Host program code:

```cpp
#define BOOST_COMPUTE_DEBUG_KERNEL_COMPILATION
#include <boost/compute.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor.hpp>
#include "kernel.cl"

namespace bc = boost::compute;

bc::device *gpu;
bc::context *ctx;
bc::command_queue *queue;
bc::program *program;
bc::kernel *vaddc64;

typedef uint64_t LIMB_TYPE;
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
ulong BITS_LENGTH =40960;
size_t LIMBS_SIZE =(BITS_LENGTH / (sizeof(LIMB_TYPE) * 8)) + 1;
ulong error_code;

    std::printf("Bits length: %lu\n", BITS_LENGTH);
    std::printf("Limbs size: %lu\n", LIMBS_SIZE);
//......................................... Host init
LIMB_TYPE a[LIMBS_SIZE], b[LIMBS_SIZE], r[LIMBS_SIZE];

    /*** init a[] ***/
    for(auto c =0; c < (LIMBS_SIZE - 1); ++c)
        a[c] =(LIMB_TYPE)-1; // a[] =0xffff...

    a[LIMBS_SIZE - 1] =1; // last (most significant) limb =1
    std::copy_n(a, LIMBS_SIZE, b); // b[] =a[]

    /*** calculation of expected values ***/
    for(auto c =0, carry =0; c < LIMBS_SIZE; ++c)
    {
        r[c] =a[c] + b[c] + carry;

        if((r[c] - carry) < b[c] || (carry & !r[c]))
            carry =1;
        else
            carry =0;
    }
//......................................... Boost Compute init
    gpu = new bc::device(bc::system::default_device());
    ctx = new bc::context(*gpu);
    queue = new bc::command_queue(*ctx, *gpu);
    program = new bc::program(bc::program::create_with_source(source, *ctx));
    program->build();
    vaddc64 = new bc::kernel(*program, "vaddc64");

//......................................... GPU init
bc::vector<LIMB_TYPE> gpu_a(LIMBS_SIZE, (LIMB_TYPE)0, *queue);
bc::vector<LIMB_TYPE> gpu_b(LIMBS_SIZE, (LIMB_TYPE)0, *queue);
bc::detail::scalar<ulong> gpu_error(*ctx);

    bc::copy(a, a + LIMBS_SIZE, gpu_a.begin(), *queue);
    bc::copy(b, b + LIMBS_SIZE, gpu_b.begin(), *queue);

    /*** GPU kernel call ***/
    vaddc64->set_arg(0, gpu_a);
    vaddc64->set_arg(1, gpu_b);
    vaddc64->set_arg(2, LIMBS_SIZE);
    vaddc64->set_arg(3, gpu_error.get_buffer());
    queue->enqueue_1d_range_kernel(*vaddc64, 0, LIMBS_SIZE, 0);

//......................................... get GPU results
    error_code =gpu_error.read(*queue);
    bc::copy(gpu_a.begin(), gpu_a.end(), a, *queue);

//......................................... Check results
auto err_idx =LIMBS_SIZE;

    while(--err_idx != (-1UL))
        if(a[err_idx] ^ r[err_idx])
            break;

    if(err_idx == (-1UL))
    {
        std::printf("Result: [%02lx, %02lx, %02lx, ... , %02lx, %02lx, %02lx]\n", a[LIMBS_SIZE - 1], a[LIMBS_SIZE - 2], a[LIMBS_SIZE - 3], a[2], a[1], a[0]);
        std::printf("Expected: [%02lx, %02lx, %02lx, ... , %02lx, %02lx, %02lx]\n", r[LIMBS_SIZE - 1], r[LIMBS_SIZE - 2], r[LIMBS_SIZE - 3], r[2], r[1], r[0]);
    }
    else
    {
        std::printf("ERROR limb index: %lu\n", err_idx);
        std::printf("ERROR: [... , %02lx, %02lx, %02lx, ...]\n", a[err_idx], a[err_idx - 1], a[err_idx - 2]);
        std::printf("EXPECTED: [... , %02lx, %02lx, %02lx, ...]\n", r[err_idx], r[err_idx - 1], r[err_idx - 2]);
    }
//......................................... cleanup
    delete vaddc64;
    delete program;
    delete queue;
    delete ctx;
    delete gpu;
}
```

I assumed that using the barrier( ... ) function to synchronize threads is enough.
Or is the problem in something else?